# Synced Table, updating the

Tags: carto

I importing live data to CartoDB using Synced table feature which is updated hourly. I also applied simple SQL to the live synced table. However, the selection coming from SQL query would not be updated hourly. Is there any way that I can set the SQL in CartoDB to be updated as well every hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a query applied to a table whose contents change (as a Sync table, or a table that you edit manually) the results of the query will change when the source changes. You'll need to refresh the page/map in order to see the new results.

If you used a permanent query that was related to your synced table, it will only have effect in the time you applied it. For example, if the query was an UPDATE, or a DELETE statement, it will not be applied again when the table syncs in the new period.

If you're not seeing the changes, make sure you're referring to the appropriate table in your SQL! (sometimes it happens to me that I'm selecting a table with similar name which is not the one I'm syncing!)

In order to test it, you can also try to use the query by doing a request with the SQL API:

```
http://{username}.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q={query}&api_key={api_key}
```